# ODE implicit method

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine the coefficient of an implicit, one step, ODE method of the form $$x( t+h ) = a x(t) + b x'(t) +c x' ( t+h )$$ so that exact for polynomial of high degree as possible. What is the order of the error? Test the validity of the formula using IVP $$x'( t) = x(t) + t^2 ,\quad x(0)= 2$$ to find the solution at $t = 2.01$.

Comment: Just for your information: To place an image in your post, you need 10 rep (so it's not very much). But you can still upload the image and add a link to it in your post (that should be the result when you try to embed an image while you haven't the required rep), and users with enough reputation can then embed the image from the link.

Comment: 10 rep ??  ... whats the meaning of rep

Comment: It's an abbreviation of "reputation". The help centre has [more information about it](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I have this homework tomorow and i dont have full answer .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the easily found (online, scripts, lexica) trapezoidal method, 
$$
y_+=y+\frac h2(f(x,y)+f(x_+,y_+))
$$
fits the pattern. Now try to find reasons that it is the only method or how any other method may deviate from it.

---

For this specific example of a linear ODE you can manually solve the implicit equation
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+\frac h2 \Bigl((x(t)+t^2)+(x(t+h)+(t+h)^2)\Bigr)
$$
as
$$
x(t+h)=\frac1{1-\frac h2}\left((1+\tfrac h2)x(t)+\tfrac h2(2t^2+2th+h^2)\right)
$$

Comment: I think thats better when i use taylor method

Comment: But i dont know how to do with implicit case

Comment: Inserting the Taylor series for $x(t+h)$ and $x'(t+h)$ should easily lead to a linear system for the constants $a,b,c$. Could you please document by editing the question how far you got?

Comment: Yes i calculate a , b,c but i dont know how to compute the solution for implicit one

Comment: Give  me full back ground plzzz

Comment: This solution mean that when i get x( t+h )  at r.h.s i translate to left and divide with 2-h /2 ?

Comment: Plz add me more detail of step for above solution

Comment: You know i get it .... thanx very mush

Comment: But the error ???

Comment: You should know that the homogeneous solution is $K·e^t$ and the trial solution for the inhomogeneous part $A+B·t+C·t^2$.

Comment: Is there exist ahomogenouse solution for taylor method ??

Comment: A what? You use Taylor to find or verify the coefficients. You use the exact solution of the Cauchy problem (IVP) to compare with the numerical solution and compute the error.

Comment: I use taylor method and insert x(t+h ) and x'( t+h ) and get a=1 ; b= h/2 ; c = h/ 2

Comment: I dont shure that using taylor method is right answer ..

Comment: Then i divide by h to get error thats right ???

Comment: What is it that you want to divide? The error should be $O(h^2)$, thus dividing the error by $h^2$ to check that the quotient is almost constant over different values of $h$ is a valid strategy. But so is also a loglog plot of the error vs. $h$.

Comment: I am new for this site but i want to add apicture to u to see my answer but i dont know how ?

Comment: You need some 100 points to be able to post pictures, anti-spam. So at the moment, you can only summarize the content of the images.

Comment: Can you give me your email and i send my answer and check it plz

Comment: In guestion we need to test the validity of the formula using i v p   i dont know how to test this ?

Comment: Are the solution for exact IVP

Comment: X(t) = -( t^2 +2t +2) + c e^ t

Comment: Now insert the initial value condition.

Comment: Are these answer true ????????????????

Comment: I solve it and c=4

Comment: But i dont know how to solve it by lagrange or deffernce method since( h ) not defined

Comment: Now you have to implement the numerical method. You can do this in Excel, but better in python, matlab or another programming language of you choice. -- For second order methods in double precision with "tame" ODE good choices for $h$ range from `1e-3` to `1e-5`. You can try out subdivisions of $2^n$ intervals, with $n=10,11,…,16$.

Comment: No this homework dont need range of h

Comment: I try to use it thanx but if you help me to write your answer  for this question